# How to create multidimensional variable list of objects using recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, list, object, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate in C# a multidimensional sequence of possible actions objects might make in 1 turn, with a variable amount of objects, and a variable amount of actions available to the object.

each object should make 1 action each turn.

For Example:    - where object is the letter, and the action it can do is the number:

possible objects/actions: a1,a2,a3,b1,c1

I have a list of Actions which have an Object as a property

I would like the multidimensional list to look like this:

- a1,b1,c1
- a2,b1,c1
- a3,b1,c1
- b1,a1,c1
- b1,a2,c1
- b1,a3,c1
- c1,a1,b1
- .....

When I started coding the function to return a multidimensional list of Actions, i realised how out of my depth i was, and so i have come here!

My current code:

```
private List<List<Move>> PotentialLine(List<Move> moves, List<Move> currentList = null, List<List<Move>> finalList = null)
{
    if(finalList == null)
        finalList = new List<List<Move>>();
    if(currentList == null)
        currentList = new List<Move>();

    //find all combinations of move for this level
    foreach(Move move in moves.ToList())
    {
        currentList.Add(move);

        List<Move> movesRemaining = moves;
        movesRemaining.RemoveAll(o=> o.card == move.card);

        if(!movesRemaining.Any())
        {
            finalList.Add(currentList);
            return finalList;
        }
        else
        {
            finalList = PotentialLine(movesRemaining, currentList, finalList);   
        }
    }
    return finalList;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Even if your code was not good enough, maybe you could still share it. Also add: based on what rules are you deciding which object/action combinations are possible?

Comment: Please post some pseudo-code, including input and expected output, so it's easier to understand what you are asking

Comment: "I have a list of Actions which have an Object as a property" - Does this sound like the correct way to model this problem? Surely it would make logical sense for an object to have a list of possible actions, rather than an action have a list of objects that can do it.

Comment: You say you want a multidimensional sequence of possible actions. Why multi-dimensional? Don't you just want a list of actions that can be applied to an object? How are the actions determined? Where do these objects come from? What *type* are the objects? Do they share a common interface or base class? What do you mean by "turn"? Do you mean an iteration in a loop? Is this a game? Please add some actual (minimal) classes that represent what you're talking about, and a description of the actual scenario. Your question is too abstract and unclear for anyone to provide a decent answer.

Comment: Edited to include the code i have so far

Comment: So, input: List of possible moves --> where move = Card, Valid Target of action  

Output: Every possible combination of move in a list where every card takes 1 action

Comment: I will then loop through every combination to find the optimal combination based on the board state using weightings

Comment: @JeffTaylor - When responding to someone you should the `@` symbol so that they get a notification. You can only do one notification per comment, so it's best to split the replies into separate lines. That also makes it easier to follow too.

Comment: @JeffTaylor - I'd suggest redoing your mega-comment so that each person gets the notification. They may not have seen your reply.

Comment: @Enigmativity ahh thanks for that, will do!

Comment: In response to comments: @HansKeﬆing: At this stage, i am not determining whether the actions are legal - just possible.. i will determine if action is legal after i have this list.

Comment: @JMad : it is true that the cards have actions they do... it is moreso that on the board they can do that action to many individuals (action == move)

Comment: @Rufus : I chose multidimensional because i want a list of a list of available actions. The objects are cards, which can be different types, which do different actions based on their type, and affect different types/owner of cards. (Like hearthstone, or MTG).

Comment: So one dimension is the card type and the other is the actions that the card can do? Perhaps instead of *"a list of Actions which have an Object as a property"*, the different card types should carry with them their own list of actions. It's a little hard to say without a more specific example. Also, it might be better if you consistent terms like "Move" and "Card" (and showed a minimal example of their definitions) instead of "Action" and "Object" (since both `Action` and `object` are already known terms in C#).